# Updating data extract activity in SFMC using SSJS/Rest API

Tags: salesforce-marketing-cloud, ssjs, salesforce-developer, salesforce-rest-api

I am working on achieving dynamic file names for file exports from SFMC. Currently, I can update the file transfer activity through an API call. However, I am encountering challenges in finding resources on how to update the data extract using API or SSJS. A solution using REST API will be very helpful.

I am unable find the endpoint and Rest API parameters for the data extract activity